# Is there a generic strategy for using AutomationId property in a WPF/Silverlight application?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, ui-automation, acceptance-testing

The AutomationProperties.AutomationId attached property seems to have two purposes:

1. Identifying UI controls during automated acceptance tests.
2. Accessibility.

Given that there are many cases when UI controls are generated at runtime (e.g. data-bound treeviews) which force the acceptance tests to search for controls using other means, when does it make sense to actually set a value for AutomationId, and what value?  Is it an abitrary process to decide which controls should have them and which shouldn't?  Or is there some general guideline that all developers can follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AutomationId is really for test purposes, so how you use it depends in how you want to test your app (or, for an app built by a team rather than an individual, how the test group wants to test the app). The key use for AutomationId is to allow the test code to reliably find an element without having to refer to something like Name, which can change on different localized builds (or which may change as the UI is tweaked during development). There's no requirement to use AutomationId at all; if test has some other means of identifying elements, they can use that instead and leave AutomationId unassigned.

Accessibility generally doesn't use it. It doesn't mean anything to an end-user, and isn't guaranteed to be present for any given control; so there's little useful that can be done with it.

Test and Accessibility do have a bunch of overlap; there are parts of UIAutomation that serve both, but also parts that serve only one or the other; AutomationId is one of the pieces that is specifically for testing.

Answer (score 0):

It's arbitrary. The QA team should know about the controls that they'll need during automated UI tests, and you need to individually assign to them unique Id to simplify the work for testers. At least that's how I understand it. I haven't come across any guidelines regarding this.